# Save state of TCP socket (connection) after page refresh

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, tcp, state

I'm building a node.js & express app that connects to an IoT device over TCP. On the index page of the app I am rendering the page and running a function that starts to ping the device. Eventually the device responds, I open a TCP socket, and I use socket.io to emit an event to the front end. This process takes much longer than the time to render the page.

When I refresh the page, I do not want to re-ping the device. I need to "save" the state of the connection. Knowing that the device is already connected, I should not need to re-run my connection function.

Possible solutions. My thoughts:

1. Boolean variable for TCP socket status. In the node.js net documentation I do not see a variable for socket connection status. Another stackoverflow answer said ._connected is undocumented and could work but 'this is not the node.js way'.
2. Sessions. I could save device state in a session, and keep track of it on re-load. However, based on my reading I can't save the session information after the res.render is called. I specifically want to save the connection status *after* reload.
3. Use a local variable. However this is 'reset' on page load.
4. Save state in JSON file. Use a separate deviceState.js file with state information. I could export that file and use it as a required module in my index page.

**My question is - how can I save the state of the device connection even when the page is reloaded?** My hunch is there is some combo of session and local variable but I am not sure how these could work based on my points above.

Here's a simplified version of the index route. Let me know if it is missing anything that would help solve this problem:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    function connectToDevice() {
        // ping device and open TCP socket...
        // eventually the following function is called as an eventlistener to
        // a net socket.on('connect')...
        function onConnect(socket) {
            res.io.emit('machine-online');
        }
    }
    connectToDevice();
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Page title'
    });
}
```

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow. I am still learning the relevant key words and have been unable to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: I would use a session, are you sure about the fact of `res.render`? Have you tried? In any case I think you could use promises for a synchronized call, if it is acceptable for the page to hang for the server's answer, and then let `res.render` execute.

Comment: Not acceptable to hang https://github.com/expressjs/session "This method [session.save()] is automatically called at the end of the HTTP response if the session data has been altered (though this behavior can be altered with various options in the middleware constructor). Because of this, typically this method does not need to be called. There are some cases where it is useful to call this method, for example, long- lived requests or in WebSockets." So because I have given a response (res.render), the session is auto saved. I am not sure if I can save the session info again explicitly.will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is #4, save state in external JSON.

deviceStatus.js: File at the root of the app structure that holds some information in JSON object.

```
var status = {};
var deviceStatus;

deviceStatus = function() {
    status = {
        "isOnline": false,
        };
    return status;
};

module.exports = deviceStatus();
```

Then in my index.js: Require the deviceStatus module.

```
var status = require('../deviceStatus');
```

And I am using this to render the page: In the (not shown) connectToDevice() function, I set status.isOnline == true. So here, if the device is offline, then I connect and render the page. If not, only render the page, do not connect.

```
if(status.isOnline == false) {
        connectToDevice();
    }
res.render('index', {
    title: 'Page title',
    machineOnline: status.isOnline
});
```

There might be a better way to do this, but this is the method that works for me. When the app re-loads the status.isOnline starts as false, which works since it is not connected yet.